# How to measure performance of Gaussian mixture?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, gaussian, mixture

I have a data set with 27211 samples and 90 attributes. This data set has no class label. I want to fit gaussian mixture to data set but I dont know how to measure performance. Can you help me?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn import mixture

trainFile = TRAIN_PATH_NAME + "train" + str(j+1) + ".txt"
trainData = pd.read_csv(trainFile, sep=",", header=None)

np.random.seed(42)
g = mixture.GMM(n_components=60)
g.fit(trainData.values)
print("IS_COVERGED: ", g.converged_)
sampled = g.sample(trainData.values.shape[0])
return sampled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not have a a ground truth (labels), you cannot give a definite estimate of the performance and have to rely on a metric of choice. It is a quite common problem to assess the quality of clusters. Therefore there is ton of documentation arround:

There are several options to measure the performance of this unsupervised case. For GMM, which base on real probabilities, the most common are [BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) and [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion). They are immediatly included in the scikit GMM class.

But there are many more metrics to measure the performance of general clusters. They are well described in the [scikit documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-evaluation). I find [Silhouette-score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html#sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score) kind of intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different performance evaluations for unsupervised learning. `scikit-learn` provides some information [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation). Some of the evaluations are mutual information. Also, [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/79079/102212) could give you some insight.